# Default Handler created in designer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

if you create a usercontrol and drag it into your form, then double click on it, this will create a sub:

```
 Private Sub MyuserControl_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyuserControl.Load

 End Sub
```

is it possible to change the default handler? for example could you produce a on click handler:

```
 Private Sub MyuserControl_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyuserControl.Click

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably have to create your own class to do this... Which is a little waste of time really, since you'd have to add a code to inherit from the custom class every time you create a new usercontrol.

But if you're interested in testing it:

```
<DefaultEvent("Click")> _
Public Class MyUserControl
    Inherits UserControl
End Class
```

Then put this in every usercontrol you create (below the Public Class line):

```
Inherits MyUserControl
```

---

Note that you will probably get an error on the `Inherits MyUserControl` line. If so, simply apply the fix that says something like "Change [class name] to inherit from MyUserControl."

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is Possible use

```
Protected Overridable Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
   ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
   Static Counter as Integer = 0
   Counter += 1
   MessageBox.Show (" This button has been clicked " & _
      Counter.ToString() & " time(s).")
End Sub
```

for information please visit

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa290043(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: sorry maybe i didn't word my question properly, i meant, is it possible so that when you double click on your user control in the designer screen, to generate the on click code instead of the onload code. thanks